# Encryption padding issue

Tags: java, codenameone

I'm seeing the following issue as crash reporting. There could be sequence of statements that cause the issue. Please see the code snippet and suggest if the sequence need to be changed as Preferences set on the first line. Please let me know.

``

```
Codename One revisions: 7dd4e7d08b3442d90959477ee52a5ae8c4361b29
[EDT] 0:0:0,3 - Exception: java.io.IOException - 
org.bouncycastle.crypto.InvalidCipherTextException: pad block corrupted
java.io.IOException
at com_codename1_crypto_EncryptedStorage.createInputStream:70
at com_codename1_io_Storage.readObject:263
at com_codename1_io_Preferences.get:84
at com_codename1_io_Preferences.get:252
at com_fluency_fluencymobile_server_ServerImpl.__INIT__:49
at com_fluency_fluencymobile_server_Server.__CLINIT__:14
at com_fluency_fluencymobile_Main.init:51
at com_fluency_fluencymobile_MainStub.run:30
at com_codename1_ui_Display.processSerialCalls:1303
at com_codename1_ui_Display.mainEDTLoop:1097
at com_codename1_ui_RunnableWrapper.run:120
at com_codename1_impl_CodenameOneThread.run:176
at java_lang_Thread.runImpl:153
```

``

Code:

``

```
public void init(Object context) {
Preferences.setPreferencesLocation("EncryptedPreferences");
Storage.getInstance().deleteStorageFile(Cookie.STORAGE_NAME);
EncryptedStorage.install("hshdjimnj");
JSONParser.setUseLongs(true);
Display.getInstance().setProperty("AppVersion", "2.1");
NetworkManager.getInstance().updateThreadCount(2);
Util.register("Activity", Activity.class);
Util.register("OfflineCommand", OfflineCommand.class);
Util.register("Appointment", Appointment.class);
theme = UIManager.initNamedTheme("/theme", "Theme");
Dialog.setDefaultBlurBackgroundRadius(10);
```

``

Answer (score 0):

Why isn't `EncryptedStorage.install("hshdjimnj");` the first line in the `init()` method?

This can happen if some code accesses preferences before the encryption took place which I'm not sure how since `init()` should be the first thing.

Notice that this is just an informative error as you can see by [this code](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/blob/master/CodenameOne/src/com/codename1/io/Storage.java#L271-L277). That code returns null if it fails to read the file and reports the error to you. This will then trigger a rewrite of the properly encrypted file when the file is saved with a `set()` call.